# Version control strategy with Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

When working with **Google Cloud Endpoints** in a appengine project (eclipse based), some files that describe the api are automatically generated every time the endpoint is edited and for every version.

The files are ***-v1.api, *-v1-rest.discovery and *-v1-rpc.discovery** (the version number may change) and are placed in WEB-INF.

¿Should these files be committed to source control?

My impression is that if the files are automatically generated, they will always be available and there is no need to track them.
Even if I add more versions of the endpoint in the future, I need to keep all those versions for backwards compatibility so all .api and .discovery files will also be generated for all the versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I don't version control (or even worry about backing up) any generated files.  I only worry about source and published binaries.  And in theory you don't need the binary either because you should be able to recreate the binary from those source files.